# (ksh) (html) Creating a table row for every single element of an array

Tags: html, arrays, shell, unix, ksh

Using Kornshell (ksh), I have 3 arrays containing *date, filename, content of file* - Array size is different everyday.

I need a  loop to create a table row for every single element in the arrays and populate them with the data in the arrays using a counter.

Therefore, is there a better way instead of manually repeating and inputting several lines like below (snippet) for every array element?

P.S. - Tried using echo `${array[@]` which is only good for the first 2 arrays. But since the 3rd array has the content of every file (very long) it is not coming good as a table format.

```
...

echo "<tr>"
echo "<td>`echo ${array[2]}`</td>"
echo "<td>`echo ${array[2]}`</td>"
echo "<td><pre>`(cat "${array[2]}")`</pre></td>"
echo "</tr>"

echo "<tr>"
echo "<td>`echo ${array[3]}`</td>"
echo "<td>`echo ${array[3]}`</td>"
echo "<td><pre>`(cat "${array[3]}")`</pre></td>"
echo "</tr>"

...
...
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate

```
len=${#date[@]}
for ((i=0; i<len; i++)); do
    echo "<tr>"
    echo "<td>${date[i]}`</td>"
    echo "<td>${filename[i]}`</td>"
    echo "<td><pre>$(< "${filename[i]}")</pre></td>"
    echo "</tr>"
done
```

You don't need to `echo` a variable to get its contents, just dereference it.

`$(< filename)` is equivalent to `$(cat filename)`, but it's built-in to the shell

Answer (score 0):

Like in any language, use a loop:

```
dates=(...)
filenames=(...)
contents=(...)
for ((i=0; i<${#dates[@]}; i++)); do
  echo "<tr>"
  echo "<td>${dates[i]}</td>"
  echo "<td>${filenames[i]}</td>"
  echo "<td><pre>${contents[i]}</pre></td>"
  echo "</tr>"
done | sendmail ...
```